# T-SQL applying pivot for two rows under a single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

On SQL Server 2014 I use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
LType varchar(255),
LStatus varchar(255),
PAmount decimal(16,2),
RAmount decimal(16,2));

INSERT INTO TempTable (LType, LStatus, PAmount, RAmount)

VALUES ('TypeA','StatusA', '1000', '10'),
       ('TypeB', 'StatusC', '500', '50'),
       ('TypeC', 'StatusB', '2500', '100'),
       ('TypeB', 'StatusB', '1000', '50'),
       ('TypeA', 'StatusA', '3000', '25'),
       ('TypeC', 'StatusB', '2200', '50');



       Select Ltype, Lstatus, SUM(PAmount) as PAmount, SUM(RAmount) as RAmount

        From TempTable 

        Where PAmount > 0 
        Group By LType, LStatus
```

to get this table:
[image]

What I’m trying to achieve is:
[image]

I used `pivot` but was unable to apply it simultaneously for PAmount and RAmount under Status columns.
Can anyone help with solution?

Comment: You can't. What you can is to add the `Stutus` in the `Amount` column with concatenation.

Comment: This is a presentation layer thing, not a sql server thing. In sql server we return columns and your headers contradict the concept of columns. You really should post data as something consumable instead of pictures. I was going to show you how you can do everything other than those headers but I just don't have to patience to type in your sample data.

Comment: @Sean Lange Sorry, I've added sample query, maybe this will help?

Comment: Not really. The reason we want data is so we can write a query and test it.

Comment: @SeanLange I've added data. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this. This assumes you will always have these values. If you need this to be dynamic then there is a bit more work to do.

```
select StatusA_PAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusA' then Totals.PAmount end)
    , StatusA_RAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusA' then Totals.RAmount end)
    , StatusB_PAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusB' then Totals.PAmount end)
    , StatusB_RAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusB' then Totals.RAmount end)
    , StatusC_PAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusC' then Totals.PAmount end)
    , StatusC_RAMount = max(case when Totals.Lstatus = 'StatusC' then Totals.RAmount end)
from 
(
    Select Lstatus
        , SUM(PAmount) as PAmount
        , SUM(RAmount) as RAmount
    From TempTable 
    Where PAmount > 0 
    Group By LStatus
) Totals
```